# What is SQL/PSM and how does it differ from other versions of SQL like T-SQL?

Tags: sql, database, t-sql

I've wiki'd SQL/PSM and I know it stands for Structured Query Language/Pesistent Stored Modules. I'd like to know what it really is and how it differs from T-SQL and any other versions of SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Persistent Stored Modules exist in many different database technologies. Their interfaces are different and the actual declarations and out can be different as well. But in general, it is a way of keeping SQL programming code & logic bundled at the SQL server level.

Answer (score 2):

SQL-PSM is an ISO standard like SQL. But since SQL does not have procedural capabilities, SQL-PSM came in to extend SQL to define those capabilities.

There is a wikipedia entry for [SQL-PSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL/PSM).

There are many commercial databases which implement this standard.
IBM DB2, MySQL and PostgreSQL e.t.c. Taken from wikipedia entry for [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

Comment: None of the mentioned DBMS actually comply with the PSM standard though

Comment: Wikipedia is not a great reference to point to at the first place. Thought it might be a good starting point for beginners (like me)

Answer (score 1):

*I think*... PSM is just a generic term for "Stored Procedure" in TSQL.

A stored procedure is basically just a bunch of TSQL (can be as simple as a single SELECT statement, or as complicated as you please) that can take parameters, execute DML / DDL / and other operations, and report on it's final status (success or failure) that gets compiled into a single execution plan.

Also known a Stored Procedure or just 'Procedure' in PL/SQL -- it's basically the same thing there.

SQLlite doesn't have stored prodecures...

Comment: It's a lot more than just a "generic term" for stored procedures. It's an ANSI standard that defines *how* those procedures look like and what kind of language elements they support. It also defines the syntax for those. T-SQL is very far from that standard.